# Notation involving field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am currently reading notes on Galois Theory and have come upon the following proposition,

> Let $f(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of a generator $\alpha$ of a finite field extension $k(\alpha)$ of $k$. Then extension $k(\alpha)/ k$ is normal iff every root $\beta$ of $f(x)=0$ lies in $k(\alpha)$ iff $f(x)$ factors into linear factors in $k(\alpha)[x]$

$\textbf{Question:}$ What is $k(\alpha)/k$ the extension of? Usually I have seen this notation to represent a quotient ring, field, etc. but that doesn't make sense, to me, in this situation. In this case, does the notation represent something else?

Comment: My guess is an extension of $k$ since it can't be an extension of $k(\alpha)$ but I'm not totally sure.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $k(\alpha)/k$ is used to say: the field $k(\alpha)$ over $k$. For fields $L/k$ it is similar: $L$ is an extension over $k$. Other notations include $L:k$, $L\mid k$.

Comment: Also $L \supset k$.